# ClientRequestFilter throws BeanCreationException if invoked in different thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, executorservice

I have a spring-boot app A which calls another service B in a different thread.

MyHeaderFilter gets called before service B is called.

As ClientRequestFilter gets invoked in different thread it does not aware of the spring bean .

How to access SomeBean without changing SpecialLogger

```
@Component
@Provider
public class MyHeaderFilter implements ClientRequestFilter
{
    @Inject
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws 
    IOException {

        someBean.someMethod(); // Here I get BeanCreationException
    }
}


@Component
public class SpecialLogger
{
   @Inject
   private ExecutorService executorService;

   public void logPayload(String data){
       Future<Void> rt = executorService.submit( 
          /* Here it calls another service B */
          );
   }
}
```

I need to access SomeBean in MyHeaderFilter without changing SpecialLogger

Comment: When asking about an exception, **always** post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Your code an explanation doesn't seem to quite add up for me. What does SomeBean have to do with SpecialLogger and service B and why is it a problem?